# Configuring data source in jboss 6-Error

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, atg, atg-dynamo

I am trying to configure the data source in jboss 6.

Below is the configuration what i have done, when I check the admin console could see the enabled=true, but when I start and run I could see the below error

I have the oracle ojdbc6.jar installed, it is in deployment folder and in deployed state, I am using oracle 11.2 server and using JdK 1.7.

I tried going through other forum but does not find any answer....Any help on this, whether I am configuring it correct, why I am not able to get the meta data

ERROR:

```
18:18:21,150 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:709)
```

Error 2

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes   from [Module "deployment.test.ear.atg_bootstrap_ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at atg.adapter.gsa.OracleStoredProcedureHelper.initialize(OracleStoredProcedureHelper.java:133) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
```

DataSource Configuration.

```
     <datasources>
    <drivers>
                <driver module="com.h2database.h2" name="h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
    </drivers>
    <xa-datasource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:/prodDs" pool-name="prodDs" use-java-context="true">
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXX:1521:test</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="User">XXX</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">XXXX</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>XXX</user-name>
        <password>XXXX</password>
    </security>
    <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
    </xa-pool>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>

    <!-- To avoid deadlocks you need set this -->
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    </xa-datasource>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your datasource configuration change your driver tag  as follows

```
<drivers>
              <driver name="ojdbc6.jar" module="com.oracle">
                 <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
              </driver>
           </drivers>
```